# Flutter terminated notification is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

first time when i run my app and terminate it, my terminated notifications work good, but if i run it again and terminate, i got this error in my run terminal[image: error after second run],
and my notification is not received. Is it flutter issue.
is this a flutter error or my api error?

Here is my terminated notification code

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
await Permission.notification.request();
await Permission.camera.request();
await Permission.microphone.request();

RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

await _messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
  alert: true,
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);
```

I tried to reboot my computer, and restart my androidStudio, but it does not help.

Comment: When you terminate your app, you lost your connection to device. it's normal. So you can't try it to debug mode. "flutter run --release" and send your notification with postman to try it

Comment: thank you, in release mode terminated messages work good